# Add custom button for Jira issue

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Is it possible to add button in jira issue without any add-on plugins?
I need one button in issue page, after click on button I should redirect to given button url along with some issue details as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use any of these addons:

- [**JsIncluder**](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211670/jsincluder?hosting=server&tab=overview) (you can easily include custom JS per project or issue type) (*FREE*)
- [**ScriptRunner**](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview) (and its [Web Fragments](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/CustomisingUI.html)) (*PAID*)

Answer (score -1):

If you goal to do it without any add-on - try use Announcement banner. You can include js script to banner and draw button from this script by any way easy to you. Announcement banner runs in every single Jira page. Therefore perhaps better to determine that user is on issue page through check url path or page content or whatever else before draw a button.